# why we use this code please can any one tell me

Tags: android

submitButtonLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.submit_button_layout);

```
    submitButtonLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,  android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);

            if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{ android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}, Utils.REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE);
            } else {
                loginAction();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: for device who has marshmallow or greater OS version

Comment: This code is for checking permission for marshmallow or greater OS. If permission granted for READ_PHONE_STATE then loginAction(); will call otherwise the popup opens to grant the permission for READ_PHONE_STATE

Comment: check this http://www.truiton.com/2016/04/obtaining-runtime-permissions-android-marshmallow-6-0/

Comment: Thanks Brother  Zaki Pathan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

```
Beginning in Android 6.0 (API level 23), 
users grant permissions to apps while the app is running,
not when they install the app.
This approach streamlines the app install process,
since the user does not need to grant permissions when they install or update the app.
It also gives the user more control over the app's functionality; 
for example, a user could choose to give a camera app access to the camera but not to the device location.
The user can revoke the permissions at any time, by going to the app's Settings screen.
```

Basic overview of what you need. Go through the link to get more details about implementation and other restrictions.

Comment: Thank You Brother..mohammed-atif